# Weird hair error

Tags: animation, particles, hair

I have a weird problem in 2.78c. I have a simple animated tail (a cone with a few bones). When I add Particle hair to it, instead of growing naturally (perpendicularly to the body), it looks like weird unidirectional spaghetti. I tried to recalculate and flip normals but to no avail. Can anybody please help?

Here's the blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ph652ojf41ki1r/tail2.blend?dl=0

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the scale of your object in Object > Apply > Scale

Comment: Thank you! Definitely much better, but still weird! Any further tip please?

http://imgur.com/a/pKpx2

Comment: that's because your mesh tessellation is very uneven. The quads should be closer to squares.